# Store Linux Terminal output to file

Tags: linux, bash

I would like store the terminal output to a file. I execute the command and cannot view the terminal output in the file but I am able to view the output in the terminal. Kindly help.

```
./bbmap.sh in=sequence.fasta covstats=constats.txt covhist=covhist.txt basecov=basecov.txt bincov=bincov.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `sample.txt` file is empty? Maybe the script doesn't produce any output. What does `bbmap.sh` do?

Comment: The `for` loop could be written as simply `cp * "$dstdir"`. It's generally a bad idea to parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: There's no point in redirecting the output of `rm BBMap.java`, since `rm` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Maybe the output is going to standard error, not standard output. Try adding `2>&1` so stderr is also redirected to the file.

Comment: There is a trailing dot in this line: `./hello_world.sh > sample.txt.` Is this a typo? Otherwise look for a file `sample.txt.`

Comment: It looks like you should use a variable for `/home/xyz` — maybe `$HOME` or something to avoid repeating it all the time.

Comment: @Boldewyn: Hmm — that dot was a leftover from the end of a sentence when I moved the command line out into the code block.  I'll remove it and give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: When I run the ./bbmap.sh just process a java file and gives the below output. I want this output to be displayed in file but it file remains blank after executing the command. 
Genome:                 1
Key Length:             13
Max Indel:              16000
Minimum Score Ratio:   0.56
Mapping Mode:          normal
Reads Used:            5036 (2517620 bases)

Mapping:           6.698 seconds.
Reads/sec:        751.82
kBases/sec:       375.85

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, add "command 2> file". T

Answer (score 1):

Validate the output of the script without redirecting to a file.
You can also pipe the output through tee so the output will be shown before sending it to a file.
    `script.sh |tee script_output.txt`

Comment: thanks, I tried it, I am able to see the output in the terminal but still the file is blank.